# MySQL: Get all entries in a specific time frame with value=0 unless there's an entry in the same time frame with value=1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table **payment_transaction**

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+
| ID | user_id | status | time_stamp |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
|  1 |    1    |    1   | 1414541884 |
|  2 |    2    |    0   | 1414576722 |
|  3 |    2    |    0   | 1414577273 |
|  4 |    3    |    0   | 1414782966 |
|  5 |    3    |    1   | 1414785691 |
|  6 |    4    |    0   | 1415112933 |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
```

This table stores all payment transactions. `status = 0` means the payment failed for whichever reason, `status = 1` means the payment was successful.

I'd now like to setup a cronjob, where all users will get a message who weren't able to buy a membership in the last 7 days. As in the example table above, I only need 2 rows with the `user_id`, `transaction_id` of the most recent payment and `time_stampe` of the most recent payment. As `user_id = 3` managed to get a membership after the first failed payment, he should be excluded:

```
+---------+----------------+------------+
| user_id | transaction_id | time_stamp |
+---------+----------------+------------+
|    2    |       3        | 1414577273 |
|    4    |       6        | 1415112933 |
+---------+----------------+------------+
```

Is it possible to get all this done in one query? And if yes, is it more effective than using two queries?

What I've got so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `t`.`user_id`,
    `t`.`id` AS `transaction_id`,
    `t`.`time_stamp`
FROM `payment_transaction` AS `t`
WHERE
    `t`.`status` = 0
    AND `t`.`time_stamp` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 60*60*24*7
ORDER BY
    `t`.`id`
```

However, it doesn't exclude the user with `user_id = 3` and also gives me the first failed payment instead the most recent.

---- EDIT ----

Thanks to RST for providing a solution in the comments below. After some additional changes, the final query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    `t`.`user_id`,
    MAX(`t`.`id`) AS `transaction_id`,
    MAX(`t`.`time_stamp`) AS `time_stamp`
FROM `payment_transaction` AS `t`
WHERE
    `t`.`status` = 0
    AND `t`.`time_stamp` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 60*60*24*7
    AND `t`.`user_id` NOT IN (
        SELECT `user_id`
        FROM `payment_transaction`
        WHERE `status` = 1
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time_stamp`) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 60*60*24*7
    )
GROUP BY
    `t`.`user_id`
ORDER BY
    `t`.`id`
```

Comment: I would query for (in pseudocode) 'status is 0 and user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id WHERE status is 1)'.

Comment: @RST How didn't I thought of it myself... so simple. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Icefyre you are welcome. Glad you could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking a little away from your request but should still get the same results, depending on how you've coded your application. Is the assumption that the latest transaction will be the most relevant an accurate one?

If so, you could look at something like the following (untested):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `t`.`user_id`,
    `t`.`id` AS `transaction_id`,
    `t`.`time_stamp`
FROM `payment_transaction` AS `t`
WHERE
    `t`.`time_stamp` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 60*60*24*7
GROUP BY
    `t`.`user_id`
ORDER BY
    `t`.`id`
```

Please note I've not tested this SQL, as I'm away from my dev machine. I'd recommend having a look through the intricacies of the GROUP BY command to make sure you're not going to have some edge cases that aren't caught.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS payment_transaction;

 CREATE TABLE payment_transaction
 (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,user_id INT NOT NULL
 ,status INT NOT NULL
 ,time_stamp BIGINT NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO payment_transaction VALUES
 (1 ,1 ,1 ,1414541884),
 (2 ,2 ,0 ,1414576722),
 (3 ,2 ,0 ,1414577273),
 (4 ,3 ,0 ,1414782966),
 (5 ,3 ,1 ,1414785691),
 (6 ,4 ,0 ,1415112933);

 SELECT x.* 
   FROM payment_transaction x
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT a.user_id
             , MAX(a.id) max_id
          FROM payment_transaction a 
          LEFT 
          JOIN payment_transaction b 
            ON b.user_id = a.user_id 
           AND b.status = 1 
           AND b.time_stamp > a.time_stamp 
         WHERE a.time_stamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-604800
           AND a.status = 0 
           AND b.id IS NULL
      ) y
     ON y.user_id = x.user_id
    AND y.max_id = x.id;
 +----+---------+--------+------------+
 | ID | user_id | status | time_stamp |
 +----+---------+--------+------------+
 |  6 |       4 |      0 | 1415112933 |
 +----+---------+--------+------------+
```